# How to use define raycast hit variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make to define a rays hitdata like this. I am using c# unity2d. I am also trying to make the ray rotate to and also defined a drawray to display it and define the string of the hitdata and tag of the hitdata. Also this is one of the first times using raycast to.

```
    void Update()
    {
         Quaternion q = Quaternion.AngleAxis(100*Time.time, Vector3.up);
         Vector3  d = transform.forward *20;
         Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position,q*d, 0);
         RaycastHit hitData;
         Debug.DrawRay (transform.position,q*d,Color.green);                
         float hitDistance = hitData.distance;
         string tag = hitData.collider.tag;
    }
```

Comment: You never populated hitdata.